# How do I get a background location update every 1second in my iOS application?

Tags: objective-c, gps, xcode5, cllocationmanager, ios7.1

I'm looking for a way to get a background location updates forever. I'm using iOS 7.1.

Current Scenario : It is running fine in background but not forever. After every 22 to 30 minutes, GPS Location updates gets suspended.

Note : We get GPS update forever as long as we are moving but when we stop for more than an hour the location update get suspended automatically by OS...again when we start moving the OS does not resume/detect the location update automatically...

So first question is :

How to re-invoke location service from that 22nd or 30th minute so that it can run continuously and forever?

Below set of properties we have set our application plist file :

Required Background Modes :

- App registers for location updates
- App provides Voice over IP services
- App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay

And also we have done this :

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    _bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:_bgTask];
        _bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
```

where _bgTask is UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.

Secondly we also want to capture the GPS Location update in every 1 second. For that we have written a separate timer to capture that location update. please note that once the GPS location update gets suspended by the OS it also suspend our timer.

So second question is : How can I run the timer forever in the background?